# Cannot find Kinect.h file when compiling C++ code

Tags: c++, kinect

I'm trying to compile a C++ code using Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition 2017.

I tried to include the Kinect header file(Kinect.h) but I'm getting errors when compiling saying that there's no such file/directory.
(By the way, I'm using Kinect v2 sensor)

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30428719/visual-studio-2013-and-kinect-sdk-2-0-cannot-find-or-include-nuiapi-h), however I've confirmed that the Microsoft Kinect SDK Path(C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Kinect/v2.0_1409) has already been added to my Environment Path Variables.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Was it added to your project include path? That's where it should be.

Comment: Umm, I'm rather new to Visual Studio but how do I add that path?

Comment: Right-click the project in "Solution Explorer" --> "Properties". Tree to the left: "VC++ Directories" --> to the right: "Include Directories"

Comment: It worked, thanks!